# Transferring text input into label if textbox is filled

Tags: string, if-statement

I have a textbox input which needs to check if text is filled or not. However, im still seeing "please enter player name" if i enter some characters in the textbox.

If the textbox is filled, it is supposed to transfer input text for player 1 to the label above player 1, reset the textbox and player 2 will enter in the checkbox and transfer to label above player 2.

[image]

```
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lblP1name.Text = tbxPlayer.Text;
        //lblP2name.Text = tbxPlayer.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter player name");
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            lblP1name.Text = tbxPlayer.Text;
        }
    }
```

What else do I need to add so that it answers the condition required? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) == true)`

where is `input` declared? please try adding before the condition:

```
string input  = tbxPlayer.Text;
```

Alternative:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxPlayer.Text) == true)
```

**Edit**

Just check if `lblP1name.Text` is null or empty assign the input to `lblP1name.Text`, else to `lblP2name.Text`

```
input = tbxPlayer.Text;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter player name");
    return;
}
else
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblP1name.Text)) // If no name is assigned to player 1
    {
        lblP1name.Text = tbxPlayer.Text;
    }
    else // If name is assigned to player 1
    {
        lblP2name.Text = tbxPlayer.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Input was declared as  string input = ""; at public partial class. Thanks. I am also trying to get lblP2name.Text filled after text is transferred to lblP1name. Meaning both sides gets to enter their name in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks alot. Just that when i first key in the textbox both players 1 & 2 are have the same name. Just only when rekey in the text box, the player 2 name gets updated.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you mean, can you explain it better editing your question? thanks